# How to centralize rdl report content inside Asp.Net ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, report-viewer2010

I have a set of rdl files. I used those report rdl's inside asp.net reportviewer. It works OK with my reportviewer control. My problem is, the report content is always reders far left side. I need to make the report content always render center to that reportviewer.

Is there any default property to do this??

Comment: Make the report viewer to page center ? Content handling is bit complicated.

Comment: ReportViewer is already positioned perfectly. But, the content of the reportviewer must be centralized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to centralize my content of the reportviewer using the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        $find("ReportViewer1").add_propertyChanged(viewerPropertyChanged);
    });
});
function viewerPropertyChanged(sender, e) {
    if (e.get_propertyName() == "isLoading") {
        if ($find("ReportViewer1").get_isLoading()) {
            $("#VisibleReportContentReportViewer1_ctl09").find('div').find("table:first").attr("align","center");
        }
        else {
            $("#VisibleReportContentReportViewer1_ctl09").find('div').find("table:first").attr("align","center");
        }
    }
};
```